# Example Project with C++ with Boost Lib build by Gradle

Tags: c++, gradle

I'm interested in how to work with C++ and build the application with gradle.
I already figured out how to provide a simple application without any external libraries, but when I trying to add **Boost** to the project, I faced a lot of misunderstandings, what is the correct way to do this.

So, if I get an example from my CMake project, I have the next code

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.19)
project(messenger)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)

set(EXECUTABLE_SOURCE
        socket/ClientSocketConnector.h
        ../core/socket/SocketConnector.h
        ../core/socket/dto/Message.h
        ../core/socket/utils/SerializationUtils.h

        ../core/socket/SocketConnector.cpp
        socket/ClientSocketConnector.cpp
)

set(BOOST_INCLUDEDIR C:/CPlusPlus/vcpkg/installed/x64-windows/include)
set(BOOST_LIBRARYDIR C:/CPlusPlus/vcpkg/installed/x64-windows/lib)
set(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS ON)

find_package(Boost COMPONENTS serialization REQUIRED)

include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})
add_executable(clientChat main.cpp ${EXECUTABLE_SOURCE})
target_link_libraries(clientChat ${Boost_LIBRARIES})
```

Maybe this is not the best implementation, but it's at least works.

And I trying to do the same build by Gradle.

Maybe someone can share an example where I can see the right way to include Boost library in the project, and continue have fun and pain with all of it :)

---

Currently, I have next

> build.gradle

```
plugins {
    id 'cpp'
    id 'cpp-application'
}

model {
    repositories {
        libs(PrebuiltLibraries) {
            boost {
                headers.srcDir "C:/CPlusPlus/vcpkg/installed/x64-windows/include"
                binaries.withType(StaticLibraryBinary) {
                    staticLibraryFile = file("C:/CPlusPlus/vcpkg/installed/x64-windows/lib/boost_unit_test_framework-vc140-mt.lib")
                }
            }
        }
    }
    platforms {
        x86 {
            architecture "x86"
        }
        x64 {
            architecture "x86_64"
        }
    }
    components {
        main(NativeExecutableSpec) {
            targetPlatform "x64"
            sources {
                cpp {
                    source {
                        srcDirs "src/main/cpp", "src/shared/c++"
                        include "**/*.cpp"
                    }
                    exportedHeaders {
                        srcDirs "src/main/headers", "src/shared/headers"
                    }

                    lib library: "boost", linkage: "api"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

version = '1.2.1'
```

and

> main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>

#include <boost/test/unit_test.hpp>

using namespace boost::unit_test;

int main() {
    std::cout << "hello from gradle build with boost system" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

When I trying to assemble my project, I get next error

```
main.cpp
C:\Users\natri\CLionProjects\cplusplus-gradle-trainee\src\main\cpp\main.cpp(3): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'boost/test/unit_test.hpp': No such file or directory
```